# Best-practices for comparing dates in SQL Server when there is an unknown time

Tags: sql-server

I was scratching my head why I was getting different results on two DB's, the second of which was created by backing up the first to excel and then importing that data. Queries that returned multiple rows on one machine returned nothing on the other.

The mystery turned out to be because the "restored" machine set all the imported dates to noon, so comparisons like `DTFROM<='1/1/2020'` failed because `DTFROM` was `1/1/2020 12:00:00` which is, naturally, not smaller or equal to the varchar conversion which is `1/1/2020 00:00:00`

Barring re-writing maybe 500 to 1000 queries, is there some other canonical solution to this problem? The columns in question come from ancient DB's using datetime, so using a different format for the data won't do it.

Comment: Could you update the dates to be 00:00:00 time in the second database?

Comment: Is the time component even needed? If not, you could just change the data type to `DATE`. Other than that, the next best solution would be to fix those broken queries.

Comment: @PeonProgrammer - no, it's not our DB and I have read-only access.

Comment: @Alejandro - we cannot change the data type, as noted above, it's not our DB.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz if you can't change the database because you have read only access, then I would change the queries. You have to be able to change something...Are these queries in-line sql within another code base or are they stored procedures etc?

Comment: _backing up to excel_  This is your source of your problem. Why do this? There are better ways to perform ETL (e.g., BCP). Add to that the self-inflicted problem of using a date literal format that depends on runtime settings to be interpreted correctly. Without context, it is difficult to suggest a "fix", much less a "best practice". Why not just use an actual backup / restore?

Comment: @PeonProgrammer - they are all individual SQL strings. But I guess that's the only solution.

Comment: @SMor - I couldn't agree more, and if you're willing to go to the company and train them how to use even basic SQL tools, we'd be all set! :-)

Comment: Without context, there is little to offer. Not sure what "problem" you are trying to fix. You change the code, you change the ETL process, you change (i.e., cleanup) the end result of the ETL process, something else?

Comment: The easiest solution would be if there was a setting to the effect of "ignore time section when comparing dateimes", or a similar feature in the comparison operators themselves. Similar things exist for collation settings and such, which often cause similar problems.

Comment: But there is none. You have a customer. You've been hired to do something. Seems the appropriate path is to meet with customer to discuss the issue and decide on the best path.

Answer (score 0):

Alter all the columns to [DATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of DATETIME,

```
alter table t alter column DTFROM date
```

or update all the tables to remove the time portion.

```
update t set DTFROM = cast(DTFROM as date)
```

Comment: As noted above, changing the format in the original DB is a no-go. I could change it in the local db, but then I would have two different DBs which would basically nullify the whole point.